# Selecting FACES

Tags: animation

I have recently been educated on the loop cut tool. I am taking a course on Udemy and im building a pyramind. Once I use the loop cut tool, selecting faces alongside the cut becomes difficult. It becomes challenging to select one face. any guidance on selecting one face in edit mode? [image]

Comment: could you send a sample file?

Answer (score 2):

When you see this striped behavior

[image]

This is called Z-fighting, and it means that you have some faces overlapping each other, or at least so close that floating-point precision errors make it such that Blender has difficulty deciding which face should be in front.

It looks like you have one face between these verts -

[image]

and another between these.

[image]

This problem may repeat itself all the way down these center cuts, depending on how this was made.  Actually what I think happened is that you scaled it to something like -0.5 after the loop cut.

Answer (score 0):

You have select face select tool in edit mode correctly

[image: You have select face select tool in edit mode correctly]

Thus, you may select face by clicking on object face
[image: thus, you may select face by clicking on object face]